# Facebook Marketing API returns error on "breakdowns call"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to make an API call with the folowing URL

```
act_XXXXXXXX/insights?fields=ad_id,clicks,unique_clicks,impressions,reach,spend,date_start,date_stop,actions,action_values,unique_actions,account_id&level=ad&breakdowns=platform_position&time_range={"since":"2019-09-07","until":"2019-09-07"}
```

and the response is :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Current combination of data breakdown columns (action_type, platform_position) is invalid ",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

the reason is in "breakdown" value = "platform_position"
but the problem is that I need exactly that breakdown :(

when I do an API call and change "breakdown" in URL to something else, for example to "publisher_platform":

```
act_XXXXXXX/insights?fields=ad_id,clicks,unique_clicks,impressions,reach,spend,date_start,date_stop,actions,action_values,unique_actions,account_id&level=ad&breakdowns=publisher_platform&time_range={"since":"2019-09-07","until":"2019-09-07"}
```

it is OK and responds with data.
I don't know why it happens because I'm not specifying any "action_type" breakdown but it tells that I am :(

**What I've tried:**
I tried to remove all the parameters from that URL one by one but it still returns an error

**The main questions are:** why the API call for "breakdown" value = "platform_position" fails and how to make it work.

Thanks.
**PS:** you can use [FB API testing tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test requests to FB api.
**I'm using API version v8.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need both publisher and position:

breakdowns=publisher_platform,platform_position

Comment: thanks! you helped me a lot! I don't know how did you found that solution but it works.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What I would like to know is why they say they "only" provide certain combinations of breakdowns due to space, BUT, they seem to provide all combinations through an alternate, manual tool. I have a report generated through the Business Manager tool with not only Country and Region, but also DMA, Platform, Placement, (Is) Video Asset. Can't do that with the API.